# Jquery sortable on table - dragged row y position is above mouse pointer

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

My problem is a little bit unusual - it works when I paste example on code pen, but inside my local project it doesn't work.

Problem is that when dragging row it is high above mouse pointer:

[image]

This same thing doesn't happen [in example - but HTML is the same.](https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/WMZmVj?editors=1010)

What I would like to do is align y position of dragged row with mouse pointer. Is there a way to achieve this?

For sortable functionality I use this code:

```
 $("table[id=tblSelectedCAMERC] tbody").sortable();
```

Comment: It's very hard to imagine your problem and suggest solution for it without seeing similar situation. Your code in code pen is true, but I think in real project you have `CSS`s that affect row's `align`. You can inspect your one row and then drag and drop it and see how does it's style change.

Comment: Thanks @AliSoltani. Thats exactly what I did at the end and I've found the solution. Although it wasn't align property (more in my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this row:

```
html{overflow: scroll;}
```

It was in one of the css included files on the page. When I've changed this to:

```
html{overflow:visible;}
```

everything was fine.